# Does the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3\,\cos{(x^2-x)}}{1+x^2}$ diverge

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Does the integral 
$$J:=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3\,\cos{(x^2-x)}}{1+x^2}dx $$
diverge ?

If we integrate by parts we find

$$J=\lim_{a\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a^3}{(1+a^2)(2a-1)}\cos{(a^2-a)} -\\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin{(x^2-x)}
\left( \frac{3x^2}{(1+x^2)(2x-1)}-\\
\frac{2x^4}{(1+x^2)^2(2x-1)}-\frac{2x^3}{(1+x^2)(2x-1)^2}\right)dx$$

If we integrate by parts again, we find that the latter integral reduces to 
a sum of absolutely convergent integrals plus
the boundary term

$$ -\lim_{a\rightarrow +\infty}\,
\cos{(a^2-a)}\left(\frac{3a^2}{(1+a^2)(2a-1)^2}
-\\
\frac{2a^4}{(1+a^2)^2(2a-1)^2}-\frac{2a^3}{(1+a^2)(2a-1)^3}
\right)=0.$$

So the question simplifies to the existence of the limit
$\lim_{a\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{a^3}{(1+a^2)(2a-1)}\cos{(a^2-a)}$ which I believe does not exist.

Correct ?

Comment: Correct. Assuming your math is correct, you can look at your limit and see that for large $a$ the rational bit essentially goes to order 1, and that leaves the cosine which has an undefined limit at infinty.

Comment: I am quite sure about the rest. Are you sure the limit in question does not exit ?

Comment: This isn't a proof this is an intuition for a proof. But just consider any rational function times a cosine. Unless the rational part goes to zero, the sinusoidal part will always be there, which has a non existent limit yielding a nonexistence. In any case the limit is just going to keep giving you faster and faster cosines unless the polynomial pushes it to zero. You could prob to some perverse L'Hopital magic if you really wanted to.

Comment: Dear  InertialObserver, thanks a lot for your comments.  I know this pretty well. But let me warn you about something: Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)$ exists but $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} g(x)$ does not. This does not imply $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) g(x)$ does not exist. ($x_{0}$ can be $\infty$). Think of the functions $x$ and $1/x$ and the limits at $\infty$. I already know your intuition, and that is why I said "I believe the limit does not exist" in my question. I am looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Medo the example you gave in the last comment is not correct. $\lim_{x\to\infty}x=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}1/x=0$. Both limits exist.

Comment: @ YiFan. Okay, replace the function $x$ by $\sin{x}$.

Comment: I think I figured it out. We can extract two sequences of numbers that go to $\infty$ and show that, although the rational factor tends to $1/2$, the limit yields two different values for those two sequences. The choice of the sequences is not easy because of the argumnet $a^2-a$, but I think it is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do that: an improper integral $\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_0^r f(x)\, dx$ converges if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is some $M>0$ such that $\left|\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\right|<\epsilon$ for all pairs $a,b\ge M$.

Now note that $\cos(x)\ge\sqrt 2/2$ when $x\in(-\pi/4+2k\pi,\pi/4+2k\pi)$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$. Now observe that

$$x^2-x=\alpha\,\text{ and }\, x,\alpha>0\implies x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4\alpha}}2$$

Now for $\alpha=2\pi n\pm\pi/4$ we set $a_{n\pm}:=\frac12(1+\sqrt{1+\pi(4n\pm 1)})$ and in your case you have that

$$\begin{align}I_n&:=\left|\int_{a_{n-}}^{a_{n+}}f(x)\, dx\right|\ge\frac{\sqrt2}2\int_{a_{n-}}^{a_{n+}}\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\, dx\\
&\ge\frac{\sqrt 2}2\cdot(a_{n+}-a_{n-})\min_{x\in[a_{n-},a_{n+}]}\frac{x}2,&\text{because }\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}\ge \frac{x}2\text{ when }x\ge 1\\
&=\frac{\sqrt 2}2(a_{n+}-a_{n-})\cdot\frac{a_{n+}+a_{n-}}{a_{n+}+a_{n-}}\cdot\frac{a_{n-}}2\\
&\ge\frac{\sqrt 2}2\cdot\frac{a^2_{n+}-a^2_{n-}}{2a_{n+}}\cdot\frac{a_{n-}}2,&\text{ because } 2a_{n+}\ge a_{n-}+a_{n+}\\
&\ge\frac{\pi\sqrt 2}{16}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1+\pi(4n-1)}{1+\pi(4n+1)}}\end{align}$$

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n\ge\pi\sqrt 2/16$, so we can conclude that the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: So your proof is correct if we want to show that the intergral in question does not converge to zero. In this case I would recommend adding a last sentence to clarify the logic of your proof: You have proved that there exists $c=\frac{\sqrt 2}{32} \pi$ ( notice that $\sqrt{\frac{1+\pi(4n-1)}{1+\pi(4n+1)}}>\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq 1$)  such that for every $M>0 $ there exist s a large enough $n$ (equivalently there exist $a=a_{n_{-}}$ and $b=a_{n_{+}}$ ) such that $a,b> M$ but $\left| \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\right|>c$.

Comment: Im showing that the sequence of differences $$\left|\int_0^{a_{n+}}f(x)\,dx-\int_0^{a_{n-}}f(x)\, dx\right|\to C>0$$ as $n\to\infty$, hence the sequence defined by $\int_0^{a_{n-}},\int_0^{a_{n+}},\int_0^{a_{n+1-}},...$ is not Cauchy, and because this sequence converges to $\int_0^\infty$ then the integral diverges

Comment: no, re-read the answer please. I just need to show that $I_n\to C>0$. There is no limit involved here because Im using a Cauchy sequence. Take a look [here](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/m4342f10/improper_integrals.pdf) for a longer explanation

Comment: You lost me. $I_{n}\rightarrow c$ means $I_{n}-I_{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ means $I_{n}-I_{m}\rightarrow 0$, i.e., $I_{n}$ is Cauchy and by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ convergent!

Comment: Okay. The criteria you provided for convergence checks out.  Your answer proves the divergence of the integral. Thanks a lot. If you look at my first comment, you see we do not need to use any sequential criterion. The definition you gave is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is divergent because the limit does not exist.
Let $f(a)=\frac{a^3\,\cos{(a^2-a)}}{(1+a^2)(2a-1)}$.

Take the sequence $a_{n}=:\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8\pi n}}{2}$
that diverges to infinity and satisfies $a_{n}^2-a_{n}=2n\pi$.
Then $f(a_{n})\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$.

Now, take the sequence $b_{n}:=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4(2n+1)\pi }}{2}$ that also diverges to infinity and satisfies $b_{n}^2-b_{n}=(2n+1)\pi$. Then 
$f(b_{n})\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}$.